# Use DEV compiler SDL error: cannot find -lobjc

Tags: sdl

I have one question about SDL compile, I use DEV C++ compiler a SDL program, but there is a error, the error log:

```
d:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    cannot find -lSDLmain
d:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    cannot find -lSDL
d:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    cannot find -lobjc
D:\C++\SDL\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

I learn it from : http://tjumyk.github.io/sdl-tutorial-cn/lessons/lesson01/windows/devcpp/index.html

I completely followed the course step by step to install and config ,but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDL library error: cannot find -lSDL\_ttf cannot find -lSDL\_image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645180/sdl-library-error-cannot-find-lsdl-ttf-cannot-find-lsdl-image)