# SDL library error: cannot find -lSDL_ttf cannot find -lSDL_image

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl

I'm running a C++ program using sdl, my ubuntu version is 16.04. 
After I sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev and run the following displays :

g++ `sdl-config --cflags` -g -W -Wall -Weffc++ -Wextra -pedantic -O0 main.cpp -o run generateFrames.o `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_image

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_ttf

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_image

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:10: recipe for target 'run' failed

make: *** [run] Error 1

How to get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only installed SDL library. SDL_image and SDL_ttf are different libraries. You can download them via `sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev`. There is also another popular SDL extension SDL_mixer: `libsdl-mixer1.2-dev`

Comment: Also there is SDL_net.

Comment: Thanks.after I download the mixer, "cannot find -lSDL_image" gone but  it still says " cannot find -lSDL_ttf " ? Could you give some hint ?

Comment: Well, if `libsdl-ttf1.2-dev` didn't work try `libsdl-ttf2.0-dev` and tell the result so that I can edit the answer.

Comment: I install sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev

Comment: and libsdl-ttf2.0-dev